# The front of the cards is not visible for players who are not the Master Client with Unity PUN2

Tags: unity-game-engine

The cards spawn in the characters' hands. Master Client can see whole front sides of cards but other clients cant. Material doesn't change at other clients.

My basic GameHandler code:

```
private void Start()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
        {
            DealStartingHand();
        }
    }

    private void DealStartingHand()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            if (player1Hand.Count > 0 && player2Hand.Count > 0)
                return;

            for (int i = 0; i < startingHandSize; i++)
            {
                int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 101);
                CardData selectedCard;
                if (randomNumber < 60)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Common);
                else if (randomNumber < 85)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Rare);
                else if (randomNumber < 95)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Epic);
                else if (randomNumber < 99)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Legendary);
                else
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Prime);

                CreateCard(selectedCard, i, true);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < startingHandSize; i++)
            {
                int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 101);

                CardData selectedCard;
                if (randomNumber < 60)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Common);
                else if (randomNumber < 85)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Rare);
                else if (randomNumber < 95)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Epic);
                else if (randomNumber < 99)
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Legendary);
                else
                    selectedCard = GetRandomCardByRarity(CardData.RarityType.Prime);

                CreateCard(selectedCard, i, false);
            }
        }
    }
    private void CreateCard(CardData cardData, int i, bool isPlayer1)
    {
        GameObject newCard = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Card", Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        Vector3 cardPositionOffset;

        if (isPlayer1)
        {
            newCard.transform.position = new Vector3(5.93100023f, 1.30599999f, -0.699999988f);
            cardPositionOffset = new Vector3(0, 0, i * -cardSpacing);
            newCard.transform.position += cardPositionOffset;
            newCard.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0.695217609f, -0.142567724f, 0.695217609f, 0.142567724f);
            Renderer FrontRenderer = newCard.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Renderer>();
            FrontRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", cardData.cardImage);
            player1Hand.Add(cardData);
        }
        else
        {
            newCard.transform.position = new Vector3(6.6329999f, 1.31429994f, -1.07630002f);
            cardPositionOffset = new Vector3(0, 0, i * cardSpacing);
            newCard.transform.position += cardPositionOffset;
            newCard.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0.69246763f, 0.143138438f, -0.69246763f, 0.143138438f);
            Renderer FrontRenderer = newCard.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Renderer>();
            FrontRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", cardData.cardImage);
            player2Hand.Add(cardData);
        }
    }
```

I tried make a RPC call but it didn't work. When RPC call is is executed there is only one card at Master Client's hand.

Comment: You are only running this code on the master client.  Other clients will see the card spawn (at V3.Zero) but they don't do anything with it.  RPC is the correct approach, its not clear why your RPC did not work.